# how to host gem in Github and use it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, rubygems

I have added the private gem files to new repository in [here](https://github.com/praveenitmec/testgem) but when I try to add it to my gem file

`gem 'test_gem' , :git => 'https://github.com/praveenitmec/testgem.git'`

It is not installing gem instead it trying to use it directly from Github.Like this

```
Using spring 1.4.0
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using test_gem 0.1.0 from https://github.com/praveenitmec/testgem.git    (at master)
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using typhoeus 0.8.0
```

How to install this gem from github.

The actual Procedure is the bundler has to fetch gemspec file from the Github and  by using that it will install gem in local.But for me it is not installing in the local.Did I miss any configuration.

**Got It:I came to know that if use Git for gem it wont get installed in local Thanks to K M Rakibul Islam**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your own gem, you can specify that using the `git` option in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'test_gem', git: 'git@github.com:praveenitmec/testgem.git', branch: 'master'
```

And, then run:

```
bundle install
```

This is the correct way of using a **private gem** that you don't want to share with anyone else outside your company.

But, if you want to share your gem publicly, you can publish the gem and use that like any other gem in your `Gemfile`. To know how to publish a gem, tehre are many articles online that you can search for. [Here is one of them](http://www.michaelrigart.be/en/blog/easily-publish-your-ruby-gems.html).

#### Update

If you want to use the local version of the gem, then you have to specify using the `path` option this way:

```
gem 'test_gem', path: 'path_to_your_test_gem'
```

Comment: It is asking for some RSA Password.I need to provide my github password or Which password

Comment: Not the github password. You need to add your SSH key to your github account. See this: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/
So, to makes things clear, are you intending to make it a private gem?

Comment: Also, you can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33492786/981183
which will guide you to generate ssh key and upload that to your github account. After that, you should able to follow the above mentioned process.

Comment: I had  done it before But it is asking for passphrase which i forgot

Comment: Then create a new one now again if you want and add that ssh key to your github account.

Comment: @PardeepSaini because the gem is still public. If its made private, then you wont be able to do that. You have to have proper access to do so when the gem is private.

Comment: @Praveenkumar Just to clairify, you need all these only if you want to keep your gem as a private gem. If you don't care or want to keep that as public, then your current code is fine: `gem 'test_gem' , :git => 'https://github.com/praveenitmec/testgem.git'`

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam can u see in question It is showing  `Using test_gem 0.1.0 from https://github.com/praveenitmec/testgem.git    (at master)` it is not installed in my local.It is directly using from git.

Comment: If you want to use the local version, then say you have to specify using the `path` option this way: `gem 'test_gem', path: 'path_to_your_gem/test-gem'`

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam No what I am saying If is use some other gems like **rspec** it will install the gem locally.but my gem not installing like that.

Comment: No it won't be like that when you specify the gem using `git` option.

Comment: It will be like that if you publish your gem to rubygems: http://guides.rubygems.org/publishing/

Comment: This is what the answer I am expecting Sorry to drag You till this.@KMRakibulIslam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94168/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-praveenkumar).

Answer (score 1):

Try this `gem 'test_gem', github: 'praveenitmec/testgem'`

Comment: Does that gem got installed in your local

Comment: `gem which test_gem` try this in your Machine .It wont show the gem

Comment: Just know i came to know if you use source as git then it wont get installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but the gem is definitely "installed". You can validate that by doing `gem which test_gem` from the directory your code is in.

If you want it to look like the other gems, `test_gem` must be hosted on a gem server like rubygems.org. If you own `test_gem` and would like to publish it, [RubyGems provides a lot of helpful guides to do it with](http://guides.rubygems.org/publishing/)