# Could not find testgem-0.1.0 in any of the sources?how to solve this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

On continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515699/how-to-host-gem-in-github-and-use-it/33515813#33515813) question.After bundle install it throws the above error when running the server.[link to gitrepo](https://github.com/praveenitmec/testgem)

**gemfile**

```
gem 'testgem' , :git => 'https://github.com/praveenitmec/testgem.git'
```

**during bundle install**

```
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using testgem 0.1.0 from https://github.com/praveenitmec/testgem.git (at master)
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
```

**while running server**

```
Brillios-Mac-mini:test_app_for ucs brilliomac$ rails s
Could not find testgem-0.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Brillios-Mac-mini:test_app_for ucs brilliomac$
```

Comment: i think it should be `gem testgem` instead of `test_gem` according to your github .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is I pushed with gemfile(i.e-testgem-0.1.0.gem) first Thats why it throws this error.

it is not able to build the gem in local because of the gemfile already available.