# bitbucket "The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access."

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket account. I use it as a remote backup for coding projects.

However, after a creating a repository on bitbucket and trying to push to it, I get this message:

> The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have
> access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access,
> make sure you're authenticated. fatal: Could not read from remote
> repository.

How do I authenticate from the command line?

Comment: There is a number of different mechanisms but creating an SSH keypair is the most common. Does this answer your question? [Bitbucket/Github: permission denied public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491471/bitbucket-github-permission-denied-public-key)

Answer (score 2):

Hello everyone I get this error when I tried to connect to another account in Bitbucket. If you also have multiple accounts in bitbucket, you will need to set up a configuration file for them.

There is official documentation on this: https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/

There is a response from other users:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32962481/13294806

There are several steps to achieve this (for mac OS):

1. First of all, create a key for each account `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/username1 -C "username1"`, `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/username2 -C "username2"`
2. Edit the ~/.ssh/config file. If you don't have a config file, create one.
3. Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
#username1
    Host bitbucket.org-user1
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/username1
    IdentitiesOnly yes
#username2
    Host bitbucket.org-user2
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/username1
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

4. Load each key into the appropriate Bitbucket account
5. Сheck that ssh-agent is running `ps | grep ssh-agent`
6. Check current loaded keys `ssh-add -l`
7. If you don't see your keys, add each of them `ssh-add ~/.ssh/username1`, `ssh-add ~/.ssh/username2`
8. Check current loaded keys again `ssh-add -l`

Now you can work with bitbucket, authentication will be performed automatically